# Fail all transactions if one fails in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to fail all transactions if one of a group of transactions fails?

The problem is that I have a list of items that can be 'ordered' and some of these could be out of stock.

I first decrement the `stockLevel` for each then if that succeeds, the sale proceeds.

If one of the transactions fails, I then need to increment (i.e. rollback / revert) the stock level for those items whose stock level was decremented successfully.

Example:

```
function decrementStock(itemQuantities) {
  let db = admin.database();
  let ref = db.ref("/products");
  let promises = Object.keys(itemQuantities)
  .map(item => ref.child(`/${item}/stockLevel`)
    .transaction(function(currentStockLevel) 
      if (currentStockLevel === 0) {
        return; // Abort the transaction.
      }
      return currentStockLevel -= itemQuantities[item];
  }));  

  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Is the code you're showing not working the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson it is working the way I expect. It's there just to illustrate the problem i.e. some of the item's stock level may be decremented where the others are not...

Answer (score 1):

Each transaction on the Firebase Realtime Database is its own individual call. There is no concept of a group of transactions.

The only way to modify all stock levels in one go, is to do so in one transaction. This unfortunately means that the transaction will have to run on the entire `/item` node, which makes the system significantly less scaleable.

But the scalability depends on the amount of contention, which is somewhat easier to control if you run this code in a Node.js process (where you control concurrency).

Comment: I could run it on the `/products` node but the operation should only apply to specific product's and this isn't possible with Firebase's querying / update mechanism as far as I can see e.g. `decrement these specific items' stock levels`

Comment: Having a transaction on `/products` will read the whole `/products` node. But you don't have to modify everything. Alternatively you can try to do the whole thing with a multi-location update + security rules + client-side retry on failure, which is essentially what a transaction is. I recently did that for another question. It's definitely never simple, but it's more frequently possible than many folks think.